# temporarly disable apc.stat = 0

Tags: php, apc

I have apc.stat = 0, so every time I make a change I need to delete the APC cache.

Let's say today I know I am making some changes, is there a way to temporarly (24 hours for example) say to php (maybe with SSH) to set apc.stat = 1, without changing php.ini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a cron job that runs as root. It would have to copy a php.ini version with `apc.stat = 0` over into the PHP directory, and restart the web server.

Comment: I'm not familiar with APC much - maybe there is a much more elegant way to achieve what you want. We will see whether other answers suggest anything different

Comment: cron? Maybe a simple script that I run when I need would be better

Comment: @yes well, if you can come back after 24 hours and do it yourself, sure. Just copy the right php.ini and restart the web server

Answer (score 0):

If you are to deploy changes to production server,
at the first place, you should always clear the apc cache upon changes arrived.

In another words, you can put the clear apc stat command into a deployment script.

If you are always directly upload/scp the changes into production servers,
hmmm ... is time for a change!

You can use a simple shell script to include the scp (rsync, git, svn export ...etc)
command together with this apc stat clear command.

Once you have the deployment script ready,
you don't even have to worry about when to change apc.stat.